# Completely de-indent visual block

Tags: vim

How can I map a key to completely de-indent a visual block?

The best method I know for doing this "manually" is de-indenting once with `<` and then repeatedly pressing `.`, so the mapping is:

```
vmap <leader>d <.................
```

This does work but I'd like to know the "right" way to do this. The above also only works for however many `.`s there are.

Comment: I do this a lot without mapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the steps in this [page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces) to completely trim white spaces from the left for a range

Step by step:

```
Select your block ( shift-v)
:left or :le
<CR>
```

That should do it

Comment: I think that the :%le suggested in my link is much simpler and more direct than all options suggested so far so why the negative vote ?

Comment: I just upvoted your answer to compensate that negative vote. The OP is asking for a mapping for a visual block. You only need to suggest him/her a mapping that uses `:left` and you will have the perfect answer.

Comment: sorry i already edited my answer and added the :le was just sending him the link so he can read the details but you are right a step by step helps more :) and thanks for the upvote

Comment: Agreed about the mapping. Because of the visual selection you dont want the %. a simple vmap <leader>d :le<cr> should do the trick

Comment: @Bambu thanks i edited the answer with the steps and kept the link just in case he wants to dig deeper :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a count to `<`; I usually do `50<`, which will de-indent it 50 times, which should almost always be enough.

From `:help <`:

> ```
> {Visual}[count]<        Shift the highlighted lines [count] 'shiftwidth'
>                         leftwards (for {Visual} see Visual-mode).  {not in
>                         Vi}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `<` key to de-indent you can simply delete all the whitespace in each line before the first character. You can do so by adding:

```
let @y = '0d^j'
```

In order to run this on every line of the selected block, enter command mode by typing `:` and complete the command to:

```
:'<,'>normal @y
```

Then again you can record another macro to do so:

```
let @q = ':normal @y'
```

Using this approach, you will eventually be able to de-indent a visual block by typing `@q`, which calls the macro `@y` in the background.

Explanation of the first macro:

`0` will move the cursor to the beginning of the line,

`d^` will delete all whitespace until the first character and

`j` will move the cursor to the line below

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work for multiple lines at once?

Comment: Check my edit, it works this way